# Show that a nonabelian group of ordr p^n has an automorphism of order p.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am not sure how to prove this question: "Show that a nonabelian group of order p^n has an automorphism of order p". I found a proof of Wolfgang Gaschütz that if G is a finite non-abelian p-group, then G has an automorphism of p-power order which is not inner. However, this proof is too long, and I have a feeling that this should be a fact easy to prove. Is there any better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you demand the automorphism to be outer? If not, an inner automorphism would do isn't it?

Comment: @Oblomov No, it does not have to be outer. I guess that simplifies the proof, but I am still not sure how to proceed. Should I just show that Inn(G) is a p-group itself and has an element of order p by Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: Try to follow Oblomov's hint: the group of inner automorphism of a group $G$ is isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$. As $G$ is non abelian this quotient is nontrivial and has an element of order $p$.

Comment: Thanks @YazdegerdIII. But isn't that just what I said above. Z(G) is not trivial and not G, so Inn(G)=G/Z(G) has order p^i for i=1,...,|G|-1. That means that Inn(G) has an element of order p since p divides its order. Please let me know if this is what you are implying. I just want to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Gaschutz was not dummy, so non-inner probably really is a nontrivial fact.

Comment: @IgorRivin, it is non-trivial, but you never know if recent developments in mathematics lead to easier ways in proving it. And I might be wrong but I think I read somewhere that Webb came up with a cleaner proof.

Comment: It looks like @YazdegerdIII has given a complete answer to your question.  I should mention that as written, this question does not appear to be about "research mathematics".  Which is to say, it's a great question, but maybe not for MathOverflow.  Our sister site math.stackexchange has a broader scope, and might be able to provide you with a more detailed answer, although it looks like you've figured it out already.

Comment: Thank you @TheoJohnson-Freyd. I will keep that in mind when I have a question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the complete solution's been given by Oblomov+Yazdegerd in the comments, so I only post it as "answer" to try to save this question from the non-answered questions hell:

Let $\,G\,$ be a non abelian finite $\,p-$group, say $\,|G|=p^n\;$ , then:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;1<|Z(G)|<p^n\\
\bullet&\;\;\;\text{Inn}\,(G)\cong G/Z(G)\;\;\text{and this last group cannot be cyclic non-trivial, thus}\\
\bullet&\;\;\;|\text{Inn}\,(G)|=p^k\;,\;\;1<k<n\\
\bullet&\;\;\;\text{By Cauchy's theorem there exists an element of order $\,p\,$ in}\;\;\text{Inn}\,(G)\le\text{Aut}\,(G)\end{align*}$$

Comment: While the part about the quotient not being cyclic is true, it does not seem relevant.

Comment: Well @TobiasKildetoft, that's only to quote the *usual* argument complete: " For *any* non-trivial group, the quotient by its center cannot be cyclic non-trivial"

Comment: Hmm, actually that does mean we can expand the result to have at least $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$ unless $p = 2$. Do you know if the quotient by the center can be generalized quaternion?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It is not possible for $G/Z(G)$ to be generalized quaternion. This is because every nontrivial element of a generalized quaternion group has a power equal to its central involution $xZ(G)$, say, and so $x$ would be in the centre of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt great, so the exception for $p=2$ is not necessary.